# React Application biqComfortApp has not been registered.due to require() error during initialisation or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent

Tags: android, windows, react-native

Cloned the project from Git and started it with react..
Did not do any changes in the code for the project as I just wanted to run it using react..
but I got the following error in the emulator..

### **Application biqComponentApp has not been registered. This is either due to require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent.**

I am using windows 7 but same project up and running without any problem for colleagues with mac computers.Not sure whether it is a problem in the project with windows or any installation problem in windows..
please help to find the issue..

[Error in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwUzI.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have any other react-native/node process running in another terminal. If you do, close it and then re run it, it works for me.

or else

It could be an error caused by not matching name of project and your registered component.

You have created a project with a certain name, example:

```
react-native init biqComponentApp
```

But in your index.android.js file you register other component

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('Bananas', () => Bananas);
```

When it must be

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('biqComponentApp', () => Bananas);
```